# Laravel + Xtext DSL | Using the DSL in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eclipse, dsl, xtext, eclipse-orion

I'm making a project where I have a DSL built in Xtext (eclipse). It works like I want etc...

I'm now on the process of transfering the DSL to my laravel application but I can't find anything on the web. I came across Orion, Ace and CodeMirror but no success.

My objective is to have the DSL in my laravel app, with the auto-complete (ctrl+space) and the errors showing with a red line, just like if I was on eclipse running the DSL. Of course I want to be able to read what is written on the box.

Can anyone point me the right way?

Comment: did you have a look at "xtext-web"? the wizard has the option to create a hello world example for that. Alternative you might have a look at monaco + xtext lsp + websockets (https://github.com/cdietrich/monaco-languageclient/tree/cd_xtext221 https://github.com/itemis/xtext-languageserver-example/tree/cd_websocket_2020_221)

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I've seen those but I can't get it to use my dsl